# error while trying to insert data into hive using nifi

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

hi I have transformed a file into csv using nifi and i have tried loading it into hive manually and it is working fine but while i am trying to insert same csv file into hive using nifi it is unable load data and it is giving error while using puthive streaming and here is my flow

sample csvfile:-

```
2019-12-13,9594838484,mmssr rwfhjrbf hrfbhrbfhbf jrf
2018-3-12,9534338484,mms4er fhjrbf hrfbhrbfhbf jrf
2019-5-15,9534338484,mr5ms4er fsfhjrbf hssrfbhrbfhbf jrf
```

I have only 3columns

[image]

I have added schema in convertcsvtoavro processor still i am getting error

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some example CSV input data? The error is saying that when it tries to parse one of the values to convert it, the length is -40, which is invalid.

Comment: @Andy i have added a sample csv file

Comment: I also strongly recommend switching this flow to take advantage of the record readers/writers and associated processors.  It will be far more flexible and efficient.  Possibly as simple as GetSFTP -> UpdateRecord -> PutHive3Streaming.  The UpdateRecord could be configured to read csv and infer schema, write Avro with inferred schema, and whatever transform might be needed there.

Comment: hi @JoeWitt I have will be getting text data from text using replace text i have transformed into csv file and data is clean and good and then using  infer avro schema i have given  column names and now a column name called state_name sample data of state_name(2019-06-18 00:00:07) need to convert from string to timestamp.